# Move Functions in Visual Studio with resharper like in the eclipse outline

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I want to move some functions in Visual Studio in the same class to order them in a specific way by dragging them with my mouse. In Eclipse you can do that in the outline window but so far i have not found the same function in Visual Studio. I also have Resharper, if that helps in any way. Cutting and pasting it is a real pain, because it is a big setter/getter class and i want to sort it without having to scroll too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have ReSharper, use the File Structure window to show the outline of the file, and just drag and drop items in the tree view.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it with mouse. As an alternative, you can collapse all code blocks and then use Alt+UpArrow/Alt+DownArrow when the caret is on a collapsed block line to quickly move it to the desired location.